# (Monogame) Visual studio is lagging when interacting with it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

I've just made a new monogame project but everytime i interact with visual studio (typing anything, clicking buttons, etc)
it just freezes up for like 5 seconds, sometimes crashing because of the lag, i've looked around the internet for hours now and have found nothing.

I've tried:

- Restarting vs,
- Restarting my computer,
- Disabling my extensions,

but nothing has worked.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Were any error messages generated? If so, it would be helpful to add those to your question.

Comment: I have had this happen to me. It was in my case a (D)COM error. Wait it out without touching anything and it was fine after the initial delay.

Comment: Does it happen for non-Monogame projects? E.g. a command line / console project?

Comment: In my personal experience, on an older computer, I've sped up VS noticeably by disabling integrated version control.